# Why I Can not display "person name :"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p id="display1"></p>
<p id="display2"></p>



var person1= {
    name: 'John Smith',
    hobbies: ['surfing', 'diving']
};

$("#display1").append( "<br/>" + "person name :" + person1.name  + "<br/>");

var person2= clone(person1);

$("#display2").append( "<br/>" + "person name :" + person1.name  + "<br/>");
```

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/sGK6u/)

the above code siplay person1 name.

why it doesn't display person2 ?
Many thx.

Comment: Check the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: clone is not defined

Comment: Chrome: F12; Firefox: install [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), F12.

Comment: This question should be downvoted, there is no reason that a person who is learning JavaScript should know what is the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the answer to this question

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

covers what you need, which is shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sGK6u/1/

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in your code. `clone` clones the DOM objects, why not?

```
var person2 = person1;
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery's `clone()` only clone DOM elements. Use `extend()` instead : `$.extend({}, person1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#display2").append( "<br/>" + "person name :" + person2.name  + "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error in Clone()...Use "extend" method to copy the object

```
 jQuery.extend(copiedObject,originalObject);
```